# Change background and pixel color of image

Tags: colors, pixel, psychopy

For an experiment I want to show the participants drawings from a database which includes black drawn lines on a white background. Eventually I only want to shown what is the 'drawn part' per image in a certain color. So I want the white parts of the image to be made gray, so it is indistinguishable from the gray background. And I want to show the black parts of the image (the actual drawing) in other colors, for example red.

I am quite new to programming and so far I couldn't find an answer. I have tried several things, including the 2 options below.

Could anyone maybe show me an example of how to change the colors of the image I have attached to this message?
It would be very much appreciated!
[enter image description here][1]

```
    ####### OPTION 1, not working
#picture = Image.open(fname)
fname = exp.get_file('PICTURE_1.png')
picture = Image.open(fname)

# Get the size of the image
width, height = picture.size

# Process every pixel
for x in range(width):
   for y in range(height):
       current_color = picture.getpixel( (x,y) )
       if current_color == (255,255,255): 
           new_color = (255,0,0)
           picture.putpixel( (x,y), new_color)
       elif current_color == (0,0,0):
           new_color2 = (115,115,115)
           picture.putpixel( (x,y), new_color2)
           picture.show()

#picture.show()
win.flip()
clock.sleep(1000)
```

Implemented changes as you suggested gives: TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

```
for x in range(width):
   for y in range(height):
       current_color = picture.getpixel( (x,y) )
       if (current_color[0]<200) and (current_color[1]<200) and (current_color[2]<200):
           new_color = (255,0,0)
           picture.putpixel( (x,y), new_color)
       elif (current_color[0]>200) and (current_color[1]>200) and (current_color[2]>200):
           new_color2 = (115,115,115)
           picture.putpixel( (x,y), new_color2)
           picture.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach in option one is basically correct, but here are a few tips to help you get it working properly:

Instead of saying `if current_color == (255,255,255):`, you should instead put
`if (current_color[0]>200) and (current_color[1]>200) and (current_color[2]>200):`
as even though the white parts of the image *look* white the pixels may not be *exactly* (255,255,255).

I thought you wanted to turn the white parts grey and the black parts red? In your code for option one, the lines
`if current_color == (255,255,255):
   new_color = (255,0,0)`
will turn white pixels red. To turn black pixels red, it should be `if current_color == (0,0,0)`.

If your code is still not working when these changes are made, you could try creating a new image with the same dimensions as the original one, and adding pixels to the new image rather than editing the pixels in the original one.

Also, it would help if you could tell us what actually happens when you run your code. Is there an error message, or is an image shown but the image is not correct? Could you please attach an example output?

Update:
I fiddled around with your code, and got it to do what you want it to do. Here is the code I ended up with:

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image

picture = Image.open('image_one.png')

# Get the size of the image
width, height = picture.size

for x in range(width):
   for y in range(height):
       current_color = picture.getpixel( (x,y) )
       if (current_color[0]<200) and (current_color[1]<200) and (current_color[2]<200):
           new_color = (255,0,0)
           picture.putpixel( (x,y), new_color)
       elif (current_color[0]>200) and (current_color[1]>200) and (current_color[2]>200):
           new_color2 = (115,115,115)
           picture.putpixel( (x,y), new_color2)
picture.show()
```

If you copy and paste this code into a script and run it in the same folder as your image, it should work.

Comment: You can also do `if all(current_color > 200): ` if `current_color is a numpy array.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have implemented the changes (as you can see in my original post) but it still not working. Strangely it does not give me an error code, indicating the code should be working fine. But effectively there is nothing happening

Comment: Also, after implementing the changes regarding the if-statement (see original post) an error appears:TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'getitem'

Comment: The `exp.get_file` line might be causing the error, as when I ran the code on my laptop that line caused errors (not the same error you were getting, though). When I removed that line and changed the indentation on the bottom line (picture.show() - you want to run this once the for loop has completed, not during every iteration) the code ran perfectly. I've updated my answer with the code I used.

Answer (score 1):

There are much more efficient ways to do this than looping through each pixel and changing its value.

Since it looks like you're using PsychoPy, you can save your images as greyscale with a transparent background. By using the greyscale image format you allow PsychoPy to change the color of the lines to anything you want simply by altering the stimulus color setting. By using a transparent background, whatever you see behind your lines will show through, so you can choose to have a white square, a different square or no square at all. By this method, all the calculations for the colors are being done on the graphics card and can be changed every frame with no problems.

If for some reason you need to alter the image in ways that PsychoPy doesn't inherently allow (and if speed of processing matters) then you should try to change all the pixels in a single operation (using the numpy arrays) rather than one pixel at a time in a for-loop.